# Firebase storage downloadURL containing "v0" in the url string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

After I'm done uploading image files to my Firebase Storage, I'm getting the `downloadURL` by using the method:

`uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();`

And the URL's are coming back with the following format:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT.appspot.com/o/blog-post-images%2FFILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=TOKEN_VALUE`

**QUESTION**

What is the `v0` inside of my URL? Is this some kind of versioning? Can I be sure that those URLs are stable and won't change ever?

---

**NOTE:**

I'm saving those URLs to my Firestore to later access them and display the images through my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v0` is likely just an API versioning scheme, but it is not documented. You should treat the download URL as an opaque value that just provided read-only, public access to the file. It will continue to work for that purpose, unless the token is revoked.